# How to make a flush in-counter cutting board?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, countertops

Our 1980s home had a old glass cutting board with metal frame.
We just took it out and now there is a hole in the counter.

The counter is some kind of inexpensive laminate. We don't want to replace entire counter top if at all possible.

We want to put something (cutting board?) in the counter. MOST important is that is is sealed and flush with the rest of the counter.

(We do not want any cracks or lips - as the old metal frame had that and it causes endless crumb collection.)

Help, ideas, pleaaaaase?

Comment: A picture and measurements would help.

Comment: The hardest part will be getting exact measurements.  For a cutting board I think I would like it to be a bit above the counter top.  Some silicon to seal the edges.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem where a hot pan was put on the countertop and bubbled the formica. I routed out the damaged area and squared it off to the appropriate size and depth so it wouldn't look out of place.  I found a company online that had many different types of cutting boards and they would cut them to your exact size. This worked great. It's sealed in place and perfectly flat with the rest of the counter. I've listed the link below.  I have no connection with the company and am just sharing it because it took awhile to find it.

[image]

https://www.cuttingboardcompany.com